# Move calendar events with Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write a Google script that will move from one calendar (pubCal) all events within a given time frame to another calendar (privCal).

I'm not sure why, but the code breaks at the line: "Calendar.Events.move(pubCalId, eventToMove.getId(), privCalId);", with the error message: "Not Found (line 18, file "Code")"

What does this error message mean?

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
  //pubCall: public calendar
  //privCal private calendar

  var pubCalId = "addressForPubicCal@group.calendar.google.com";
  var privCalId = "addressForPrivateCal@group.calendar.google.com";
  var pubCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(pubCalId);

  //Change date range to move events from pubCal to privCal
  var startDate = "January 1, 2018 00:00:00 CST";
  var endDate = "January 04, 2018 23:59:59 CST";
  // Extract events between certain dates in public calendar. 
  var events = pubCal.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));

  //Loop through all Calendar events
  while (events.length > 0){
    var eventToMove = events.shift();
    Calendar.Events.move(pubCalId, eventToMove.getId(), privCalId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete error? Which file was it found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following modification?

### From :

```
Calendar.Events.move(pubCalId, eventToMove.getId(), privCalId);
```

### To :

```
Calendar.Events.move(pubCalId, eventToMove.getId().replace("@google.com", ""), privCalId);
```

### Note :

- The id retrieved `eventToMove.getId()` is `#####@google.com`. But the id which is used for `Calendar.Events.move()` is `#####`. So `@google.com` is required to be removed from `#####@google.com`.

  - In your script, because `#####@google.com` cannot be found, the error occurs.

### Reference :

- [Calendar.Events.move](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.