# Getting error when i try to move my event from one calendar to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

```
Calendar.Events.move(sourceCalendarId, eventId, destinationCalendarId);
```

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.move failed
> with error: Not Found

what should i do?
when i move to this error it moves cursor here:

```
Calendar.Events`.`move(sourceCalendarId, eventId, destinationCalendarId);
```

why this error accured and how should i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

The short answer is the id you are supplying is the wrong id.

```
function moveEvents() {
  const calid1 = 'fromid';
  const calid2 = 'toid';
  const eventTitle = "Title";
  var pageToken = null;
  do {
    var r = Calendar.Events.list(calid1, {q: eventTitle,pageToken: pageToken});
    r.items.filter(ev => ev.summary == eventTitle).forEach(ev => Calendar.Events.move(calid1, ev.id, calid2));
    pageToken = r.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken)
}
```

[learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401788/google-scripts-moving-events-between-calendars-calendar-events-move-cant-find)

[and even more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755413/how-can-i-find-the-event-id-of-my-google-calendar-event)

[where my code came from](https://gist.github.com/erickoledadevrel/5a8423c38c1f5f6ca6ec50e326ca3ad5)